# Alias name causing error in the where clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

My SQL code :

```
SELECT (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   FAVORI_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
       )       AS Eklimi,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
       )       AS Okudum,
       D.Tarih,
       D.DuaID,
       D.DuaBaslik,
       D.DuaTuru,
       D.DuaSayisiSiniri,
       D.DuaIcerik,
       D.DuaMeal,
       D.DuaArapca,
       D.PID,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID = D.DuaID
       )       AS Okundu
FROM   DUALAR     D
WHERE  D.Aktif = '1'
       AND (D.DuaTuru = 2 OR D.DuaTuru = 1 AND Okudum = 0)
ORDER BY
       D.Tarih DESC 
       LIMIT 9
```

> Error :  #1054 - Unknown column 'Okudum' in 'where clause'

I wrote

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
       AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36') AS Okudum
```

But still I get the error in the query.

Comment: Wrap it with another select, and then it will recognize this column.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'D.Okudum' in 'where clause' @pedram

Comment: use having clause in place of where (in case of alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Okudum field is a calculated field in the query. This can not be directly referenced (only in ORDER BY).

So you can use in the where clause:

```
WHERE ... AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR WHERE DuaID = D.DuaID AND PID = 'L3FNCPEVME36') = 0
```

or you can make a subquery:
Make a join with EDILEN_DUALAR as a subquery.

```
SELECT (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   FAVORI_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
       )       AS Eklimi,
       ED.Okudum,
       D.Tarih,
       D.DuaID,
       D.DuaBaslik,
       D.DuaTuru,
       D.DuaSayisiSiniri,
       D.DuaIcerik,
       D.DuaMeal,
       D.DuaArapca,
       D.PID,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID = D.DuaID
       )       AS Okundu
, D.Aktif
FROM   DUALAR D LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DuaID, COUNT(1) AS Okudum
           FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
           WHERE  PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
                  GROUP BY DuaID       ) ED

ON ED.DuaID = D.DuaID
WHERE   D.Aktif = '1'
       AND (D.DuaTuru = 2 OR D.DuaTuru = 1 AND (ED.Okudum IS NULL OR ED.Okudum = 0))
ORDER BY
       D.Tarih DESC
```

Comment: doesnt work  #1054 - Unknown column 'Q.Aktif' in 'where clause'

Comment: yes i know i can use 'WHERE ... AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR WHERE DuaID = D.DuaID AND PID = 'L3FNCPEVME36') = 0' this code, but already i selected :)

Comment: again error :( 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'D.Aktif
FROM   DUALAR     D
) Q
WHERE  Q.Aktif = '1'
       AND (Q.DuaTuru =' at line 28

Comment: working,  21.9796. secs :( so late, what should we do? your first code is running in 7 secs

Comment: sorry i have seen so late your reply, error :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 36

Comment: but now! :) it has to run.

Comment: yes! :) it is running in 3.4641  secs :) congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use having clause in place of where. otherwise you need to provide complete reference name with table for example
i edit my answer please see

`SELECT (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   FAVORI_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
       )       AS Eklimi,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
       )       AS Okudum,
       D.Tarih,
       D.DuaID,
       D.DuaBaslik,
       D.DuaTuru,
       D.DuaSayisiSiniri,
       D.DuaIcerik,
       D.DuaMeal,
       D.DuaArapca,
       D.PID,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
           WHERE  DuaID = D.DuaID
       )       AS Okundu
FROM   DUALAR     D
having  D.Aktif = '1'
       AND (D.DuaTuru = 2 OR D.DuaTuru = 1 AND Okudum = 0)
ORDER BY
       D.Tarih DESC`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having Okudum = 0)

Comment: i wrote 'WHERE  D.Aktif = '1'
       AND (D.DuaTuru = 2 OR D.DuaTuru = 1 AND having Okudum = 0)
ORDER BY
       D.Tarih DESC 
       LIMIT 9'

Comment: error :  #1054 - Unknown column 'D.Aktif' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. This should run faster than my first answer, assuming that you have 2 indexes in `DUALAR.Aktif` and `DUALAR.DuaTuru`.

```
select 
    (
       SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM   FAVORI_DUALAR
       WHERE  DuaID       = D.DuaID
              AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
   )       AS Eklimi,
   D.Okudum,
   D.Tarih,
   D.DuaID,
   D.DuaBaslik,
   D.DuaTuru,
   D.DuaSayisiSiniri,
   D.DuaIcerik,
   D.DuaMeal,
   D.DuaArapca,
   D.PID,
   (
       SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
       WHERE  DuaID = D.DuaID
   )       AS Okundu
from
    (select 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
            WHERE  DuaID       = d1.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
        )       AS Okudum
        ,d1.*
    FROM   
        DUALAR     d1
    WHERE  
        d1.Aktif = '1' 
        and d1.DuaTuru = 2
    union all
    select 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM   EDILEN_DUALAR
            WHERE  DuaID       = d2.DuaID
                  AND PID     = 'L3FNCPEVME36'
        )       AS Okudum
        ,d2.*
    FROM   
        DUALAR     d2
    WHERE  
        d2.Aktif = '1' 
        and d2.DuaTuru = 1
    ) D
where
    (D.DuaTuru = 2 OR D.DuaTuru = 1 AND D.Okudum = 0)
ORDER BY
    D.Tarih DESC 
LIMIT 9;
```

Comment: @KubilayKaanDurmuş Editted, could you run again and tell that how long it executed?

Comment: 8.4150 secs now, my old code was running in 4 secs,

where D.Aktif='1' And (D.DuaTuru = 2 or D.DuaTuru = 1 and D.DuaID Not in (select DISTINCT(DuaID) from EDILEN_DUALAR where PID='L3FNCPEVME36')) order by D.Tarih DESC LIMIT 9